TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'instance') in Brevo Bulk Transactional Email NodeJS Implementation
Below is my implementation of Bulk Send and Customise Transactional Messages in Node.js
const brevo = require("@getbrevo/brevo");
let defaultClient = brevo.ApiClient.instance;

let apiKey = defaultClient.authentications\["apiKey"\];
apiKey.apiKey =
"xkeysib-xx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxx";

let apiInstance = new brevo.TransactionalEmailsApi();
let sendSmtpEmail = new brevo.SendSmtpEmail();

sendSmtpEmail.subject = "My {{params.subject}}";
sendSmtpEmail.htmlContent =
  "<html><body><h1>Common: This is my first transactional email {{params.parameter}}</h1></body></html>";
sendSmtpEmail.sender = { name: "John", email: "abc@gmail.com" };
sendSmtpEmail.to = [{ email: "brevo@brevo.com", name: "John" }];
sendSmtpEmail.replyTo = { email: "brevo@brevo.com", name: "John" };
sendSmtpEmail.headers = { "Some-Custom-Name": "unique-id-1234" };
sendSmtpEmail.params = {
  parameter: "My param value",
  subject: "common subject",
};
sendSmtpEmail.messageVersions = [
  {
    to: [
      {
        email: "xyz@gmail.com",
        name: "John",
      },
    ],
    headers: {
      "Message-Id": "<123.123@smtp-relay.mailin.fr>",
    },
    params: {
      greeting: "Welcome onboard!",
      headline: "Be Ready for Takeoff.",
    },
    subject: "+001",
    htmlContent: "<html><body><h1>+001 content</h1></body></html>",
  },
  {
    to: [
      {
        email: "def@gmail.com",
        name: "Steve",
      },
    ],
    params: {
      greeting: "Greeting 1.",
      headline: "Some bathing suits you might like",
    },
    subject: "+002",
  },
];

apiInstance.sendTransacEmail(sendSmtpEmail).then(
  function (data) {
    console.log(
      "API called successfully. Returned data: " + JSON.stringify(data)
    );
  },
  function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
); 

Even though it has been mentioned in the Brevo Docshttps://developers.brevo.com/reference/sendtransacemail
I am getting the error given below.
let defaultClient = brevo.ApiClient.instance;
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'instance')
at Object. (C:\Users\HARIHARAN REDDY\Desktop\New folder\index.js:2:37)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
Node.js v20.10.0

I have the same problem, did you find a solution?
